# WordPress comment validation

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I created a validation function for validating email address and textrea content in WordPress comment:

```
<script>
function validatetext(){
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  if (email == '' || !re.test($email)) {
     alert("Please enter correct email address")
           return false;
  } 

 else if(document.getElementById("comment").value.length == ""){
     alert("Please add your comment")
    return false;
    }   
    return true;
}

</script>
```

The above javascript code does not work as expected. Are there any grammatical errors in it?

I added onclick="return validatetext();" to submit button:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="" onclick="return validatetext();" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: that regex.. what do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: @Christ'o. Thanks for your comment. I would like to generate a popup message (with that regex) if a user enters an incorrect email address.

Comment: what would you like to filter out? it seems I can't even smuggle a grain of rice through that regex.

Comment: @Christ'o. You mean the above function is useless, right? I will remove this question. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: How did you put the email and comment control?

Comment: I meant, can you explain the regex in simple english? how do you define a valid email? as instance, `var re = /[a-z|0-9]+@[a-z|0-9]+.[a-z|0-9|\.]+/` means you only allow email with the address only made of letter and numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Your Jquery and Css in function.php

```
function pbd_vc_scripts() {
    if(is_single() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'jquery-validate',
            get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/validator.min.js',
            array('jquery'),
            '1.10.0',
            true
        );

        wp_enqueue_style(
            'jquery-validate',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css',
            array(),
            '1.0'
        );
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'pbd_vc_scripts');
```

Validation in Comment. put on `function.php`

```
function pbd_vc_init() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $('#commentform').validate({
                rules: {
                    author: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2
                    },

                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },

                    /*url: {
                        required: true
                    },*/
                    /*phone: {
                        required: true                      
                    },*/
                    comment: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 20
                    }

                },

                messages: {
                    author: "Please enter a name.",
                    email: "Please enter a email address.",
                    /*url: "Please enter website.",*/
                    /*phone:"Please enter Mobile number",*/
                    comment: "Message must be at least 20 characters."


                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_footer', 'pbd_vc_init', 999);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: Welcome  @peter  and Thanks for like